# load ajax data 10px before scroll position bottom

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
 if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())  
    {
```

this code allows to load data when the scroll position is at the very bottom

How do I modify it to load data when the scroll position is 10px before the bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= ($(document).height() - 10))  
{
    // Do whatever you want here...
}
```